# How to give margin to each page in nativescript-pdf-view

Tags: nativescript

I'm trying to show the pdf but all pages need to separate from one another. i just tried searching on google but none gave the answer.

i explored two pdf plugins

```
 <pdf:PDFView row="0" src="{{ pdf_url }}" load="{{ pdf_loaded }}" />

 <ui:PDFViewNg row="0" src="{{ pdf_url }}" load="{{ pdf_loaded }}" defaultpage="0" bookmarkpath="0" />
```

with no result. the above two display pdf but they are tightly joined to one another. i need to show each page on a black background. what to do ?

image for ref:-
https://ibb.co/Qf9phz8

Answer (score 0):

Try to wrap the PDF layout in some other layout and apply **padding** (if applying **margin** directly on the PDF layout is not supported by the plugin)

```
<GridLayout padding="20" backgroundColor="black">
    <pdf:PDFView row="0" src="{{ pdf_url }}" load="{{ pdf_loaded }}" />
</GridLayout>
```

Comment: Sorry may be because of my english you did'nt catch what i needed. Look at the image i have uploaded then you might get what i needed.

Comment: can you kindly look at the issue and improve add new functionalities to pdf plugin. I ran into similar issue today along with it i need to show the pdf in horizontal way. I don't know what to do.